# xcrun swift on command line generate <unknown>:0: error: could not load shared library

Tags: module, swift, xcrun

My goal is to try run my Swift program like a script. If the whole program is self-contained, you can run it like:

```
% xcrun swift hello.swift
```

where hello.swift is

```
import Cocoa
println("hello")
```

However, I want to go one step beyond this, and include swift module, where I can import other classes, funcs, etc.

So lets say we have a really good class we want to use in GoodClass.swift

```
public class GoodClass {
    public init() {}
    public func sayHello() {
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

I now like to import this goodie into my hello.swift:

```
import Cocoa
import GoodClass

let myGoodClass = GoodClass()
myGoodClass.sayHello()
```

I first generate the .o, lib<>.a, .swiftmodule by running these:

```
% xcrun swiftc -emit-library -emit-object GoodClass.swift -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) -module-name GoodClass
% ar rcs libGoodClass.a GoodClass.o
% xcrun swiftc -emit-module GoodClass.swift -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) -module-name GoodClass
```

Then finally, I am readying to run my hello.swift (as if it's a script):

```
% xcrun swift -I "./" -L "./" -lGoodClass -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) hello.swift
```

But I got this error:

> **< unknown >:0: error: could not load shared library 'libGoodClass'**

What does this mean? What am I missing. If I go ahead, and do the link/compile thing similar to what you do for C/C++:

```
% xcrun swiftc -o hello -I "./" -L "./" -lGoodClass -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) hello.swift
% ./hello
```

Then everything is happy. I think I could live with that but still want to understand that shared library error.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a reformatted, simplified bash script to build your project. Your use of `-emit-object` and the subsequent conversion isn't necessary. Your command doesn't result in a libGoodClass.dylib file being generated, which is what the linker needed for your `-lGoodClass` parameter when you run `xcrun swift -I "./" -L "./" -lGoodClass -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) hello.swift`. You also didn't specify the module to link against with `-module-link-name`.

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

xcrun swiftc \
    -emit-library \
    -module-name GoodClass \
    -emit-module GoodClass.swift \
    -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx)

xcrun swift -I "." -L "." \
    -lGoodClass \
    -module-link-name GoodClass \
    -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) hello.swift
```